# Creat database grant select, I get cannot find the object or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, sql-grant

I have a program that I run every month. It creates a new database. Let's use dbname.
I am connected to the server as a user with plenty of roles.

The first command is:
CREATE DATABASE dbname;

This works fine and the database is created.

The next command is:
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[dbname] to myusername;

This does not work and returns the following error:
Cannot find the object 'dbname', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I am the owner of the database.

How do I grant select to this user.
myuser is in the database.

If I log onto SQL Server Management Studio as the user that created the table, I am able to apply the read permissions to this database?

I am using SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2003 and the commands are sent to the server using VB.net

Any help would be appreciated.
TIA,
Bill

Comment: I don't think SELECT is a db-level permission. It can't find an object for which the SELECT permission is valid, which matches the name you passed in.

Comment: @Bill I see you have been online here, please provide feedback on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GRANT SELECT ON` query is incorrect; you do not specify the database operator.

The following query will work:

`GRANT SELECT ON [dbname] to [username]`